every time I run python code I get message sent: and the first line
hello I am trying to run python application on Emacs as an IDE I installed pyel and pyright from pip and package installer but now some time the result is showing and sometime it is not trying to push forward with it but I could not help it, please look at the picture to know the issue if there is something I need to download or edit have to be done please tell me I am using windows 10 and .emacs file to edit Emacs most of the time but I am new to it.
there should be a tk window showing in my desktop but it happen one time only
picture provided

I am not sure what you are trying to do, but I see a root.mainloop(), so I guess you would want to set compile-command and then use M-x (re)compile (you can prefix it with a universal argument to run the compile buffer in comint-mode, i.e. make it interactive).
You can use the following to set the compile command automatically (add-hook 'python-mode-hook (lambda ()     (setq-local compile-command (format "python %s" buffer-file-name))))

@dalanicolai yes my dear the problem is it is compiled one time then this message is showing decoding with 'cp1252' codec failed
